# netbios traffic after adding host to snmp allowed hosts

Tags: windows-server-2008, snmp, netbios

I noticed in my firewall that there was a ton of traffic for **net-bios traffic** *(udp 137)* after adding some hosts to the snmp allowed packets list in **windows server 2008**.

I could not find any documentation about why this is occurring as the snmp documentation only shows udp 161.

- Has anyone else experienced this?

The monitoring servers is outside my domain and is behind a different zone in the firewall.

Thanks

Comment: Is the netbios traffic between the server and the monitoring server?  What exactly does the netbios traffic look like?

Comment: Yes the traffic is between the web server and the monitoring server. The web server is trying to make a connection to netbios on the monitoring server but netbios is not listening on the monitoring server as it is a redhat server and not running any type of samba share.

Comment: Well you can disable netbios if you'd like.  Or use straight IP addresses for SNMP instead.

Comment: I am already using the IP addresses to the monitoring servers in the snmp allow list, which is why it is a little weird why snmp is trying to use netbios.

Comment: Run a packet sniffer on the web server to see exactly what this NetBIOS traffic is.